# Strange float behavior

Tags: c#, floating-point

```
var v1 = propertyInfo.GetValue(actor);
var v2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(blueprint);

bool isActorValueSame = v1 == v2;
```

Whenever I try to compare v1 and v2 - I receive false boolean even though both v1 and v2 are equal to 500.0f. Any ideas why this is happening? I understand that it's not safe to compare two floats, because of float inaccuracy, but I have values that both are 100% equal.

Comment: What are the types of `v1` and `v2`? Are they `float` or `object`?

Comment: You are comparing 2 different objects against each other.

Comment: Strange, because it works for other float values.

Comment: first cast actor and blueprint to the same type and compare

Comment: @tommy_kid: Please demonstrate it working for other float values fetched by reflection. I'd be shocked if that were the case. It should be boxing every time... (Unless the properties themselves are of type `object`, and the boxing has happened beforehand, and they're returning references to the same box...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `propertyInfo.GetValue(blueprint);` will return object and object is reference type so equal operator would always get you false.
try casting before comparison

```
var v1 = (float)propertyInfo.GetValue(actor);
var v2 = (float)propertyInfo.GetValue(blueprint);

bool isActorValueSame = v1 == v2;
```

Have a look at MSDN documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) for more detail on `PropertyInfo.GetValue` method

Comment: What if value that is returned can be different than float, for example some object? How Can I make this work for different types? Would it be safe to assign it to dynamic value for doing comparison stuff?

Comment: @tommy_kid If that list of types is not big and static than you can use `is` operator to check its type and then cast appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

As written by Jenish... Addendum:

```
var v1 = propertyInfo.GetValue(actor);
var v2 = propertyInfo.GetValue(blueprint);

bool isActorValueSame = v1.Equals(v2);
```

This will work, because the [Object.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.80).aspx):

> For value types, equality is defined as bitwise equality

Comment: That is not entirely correctly documented then. If you compare two decimals, 2.50m and 2.50000m, they are bitwise quite different but they are (correctly) considered equal by Decimal.Equals(). And +0m and -0m are considered equal too, although bitwise, they are different. And Decimal is a value type.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis decimal probably overloads the Equals operator. It's its right :-) More interestingly, for `double` values 0.0 and -0.0 (that are two distinct values) return true with `Equals`. `bool b1 = (0.0).Equals(-0.0); /* true */ bool b2 = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(0.0) == BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(-0.0); /* false */ `, but this is probably part of the IEEE 754 standard.

Comment: Sure. But that does mean that for value types, equality is not defined as bitwise equality.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That is the general rule of object.Equals . Every value type is then free to overload it. Clearly there is little documentation of what value types to overload it and in what way :-)